# Left align Google chart in a page using bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, google-visualization

In my page, I have the below divs

```
<div><h2>Test</h2></div>
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 1200px; height: 600px;"></div>
```

I don't have any style, other than the default provided by bootstrap 3.
But the google chart is rendered with so much empty space at left (see the screenshot)
is there a way to fix this?

[image]

**Fix Update :** 
As per davidkonrad suggestion, I added the below option in my chart

```
chartArea : { left: 30, top:30 }
```

Now it works

[image]

Comment: What is the width of the Google chart? If you change it, does it stretch or shrink? If so, you should give it more space and cover it with the whole or desired width. On the other hand, you can center it on the parent div, it should divide the wasted space to the sides of the chart.

Comment: Looks like the issue might be that the area you are giving for the chart is larger than the data of the chart itself. Is the blank area to the left part of the chart, or just empty DOM?

Comment: The chart width is 1200px. If I reduce it, the chart shrinks, but the empty space remains.
I don't have any other element, only these two elements inside the container div.

Comment: Can you post a link to the page or the full code you are using?  I'd like to test it out to see if I can figure out what is going on.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is not caused by bootstrap - can easily reproduce the behaviour in a "fresh" bootstrap 3. It is caused by the enormous width of the container.

When `chartArea` is not defined, then `chartArea.left`, `top`, `width` and `height` is [per default set to](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#Configuration_Options) `auto`, which means the chart tries to center itself inside the container, both vertically and horizontally. You can observe that yourself by setting a border around the container. Set `chartArea.left` to force the chart-position where you want it, for example :

```
var options = {
   chartArea : { left: 80 }
};
```

or

```
var options = {
  chartArea : { left: "10%" }
};
```

Comment: Awesome, it works. I was trying to fix it in the div and bootstrap  css :-)

Comment: chartArea : { left: "0" } also works if you need to have it fully left aligned (I was worried the zero would be ignored - it's not!)

Comment: I read something elsewhere that referred to `chartArea` and thought that might be the answer, but searching for the term in the Google docs page linked here returns no results. Nice work, Google. SO to the rescue!